# How to combine polymorphic and transforming serializers for nested JSON, using Kotlin serialization?

Tags: kotlin

This is a simplified example of the JSON I want to work with:

```json
{
  "useless_info": "useless info",
  "data": {
    "useless_info2": "useless info 2",
    "children": [
      {
        "kind": "Car",
        "data": {
          "id": 1,
          "transmission": "manual"
        }
      },
      {
        "kind": "Boat",
        "data": {
          "id": 2,
          "isDocked": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`children` is an array of `vehicle` objects. `vehicle` can be `boat` or `car`.

## My Problem

The information that I want is nested quite deep (the real JSON is **much** deeply nested). A **hack** solution is to model the JSON exactly by writing dozens of nested data classes that references each other. I **do not** want to do this.

My problem is that while I know how to use `JsonTransformingSerializer` to unwrap arrays of a single type, and `JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer` to work with objects of various types, in this situation I believe I require **both**, but I can't get it to work.

## What I Did

## Assuming a single type

I tried understanding how it would work if it was a single type.

If the objects I wanted where all of the same type, it would be trivial to implement a `JsonTransformingSerializer` to cut *right into* the data I want. In this example, I will assume I only care about the ID, so I can just create a generic `Vehicle` model.

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class VehicleResponse(
    @Serializable(with = VehicleResponseSerializer::class)
    @SerialName("data")
    val vehicles: List<Vehicle>
)

@Serializable
data class Vehicle(val id: Int)

object VehicleResponseSerializer : JsonTransformingSerializer<List<Vehicle>>(ListSerializer(Vehicle.serializer())) {

    override fun transformDeserialize(element: JsonElement): JsonElement {
        val vehicles = mutableListOf<JsonElement>()

        // equals: [{"kind":"Car","data":{"id":1,"transmission":"manual"}},{"kind":"Boat","data":{"id":2,"isDocked":true}}]
        val vehicleArray = element.jsonObject["children"]!!.jsonArray

        vehicleArray.forEach { vehicle ->

            // equals: {"id":1,"transmission":"manual"}}
            val vehicleData = vehicle.jsonObject["data"]!!

            vehicles.add(vehicleData)
        }

        return JsonArray(vehicles.toList())
    }
}
```

The code works perfectly. Calling it out from main, printing the result gives me:

```
VehicleResponse(vehicles=[Vehicle(id=1), Vehicle(id=2)])
```

## But they are actually Polymorphic!

Assuming one type does not work. I need to work with `Car` and `Boat`, and call their respective functions and properties.

I tried to model the structure like this:

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class VehicleResponse(
    @Serializable(with = VehicleResponseSerializer::class)
    @SerialName("data")
    val vehicles: List<Vehicle>
)

@Serializable
abstract class Vehicle {
    abstract val id: Int
}

@Serializable
data class Car(
    override val id: Int,
    val transmission: String,
) : Vehicle()

@Serializable
data class Boat(
    override val id: Int,
    val isDocked: Boolean,
) : Vehicle()
```

## What I Want

- I want to receive a JSON from a server, and instantly be able to deserialize it into a list of `Vehicle` objects, like the one `VehicleResponse` has.
- I want to navigate through a deeply nested JSON, and unwrap an array that contains various `Vehicle` objects. For this, I assume I need to use `JsonTransformingSerializer`.
- I want to use polymorphic deserialization to convert each of `Vehicle` into its corresponding subtype.

## The actual ACTUAL problem

The thing that is **truly** throwing me in a loop is that a polymorphic serializer just does not seem to fit. It's called first before I get to parse the JSON. How am I supposed to decide which serializer to use?

Here's a test implementation:

```kotlin
object VehiclePolymorphicSerializer: JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer<VehicleResponse>(VehicleResponse::class) {

    override fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement): DeserializationStrategy<out VehicleResponse> {
        println("\nselectDeserializer()\n" +
                "base element:\n" +
                "$element\n")

        // this return is a temporary hack, I just want to see the base element by printing it to the console
        return VehicleResponse.serializer()
    }

}
```

It prints:

```
selectDeserializer()
base element:
{"useless_info":"useless info","data":{"useless_info2":"useless info 2","children":[{"kind":"Car","data":{"id":1,"transmission":"manual"}},{"kind":"Boat","data":{"id":2,"isDocked":true}}]}}
```

That's the whole initial JSON! How am I supposed to decide which deserialization strategy to use, if both `Car` and `Boat` are in there? The `JsonTransformingSerializer` is called *after* the `JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer`.

Really not sure how am I supposed to proceed here. Would *really* appreciate even a slight hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kotlinx.serialization` can handle polymorphic deserialization in this case without custom `JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer`. You just need to preserve [class descriminator](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-json/kotlinx-serialization-json/kotlinx.serialization.json/-json-builder/index.html#kotlinx.serialization.json%2FJsonBuilder%2FclassDiscriminator%2F%23%2FPointingToDeclaration%2F) in the JSON returned from your `JsonTransformingSerializer`:

```kotlin
object VehicleResponseSerializer : JsonTransformingSerializer<List<Vehicle>>(ListSerializer(Vehicle.serializer())) {
    override fun transformDeserialize(element: JsonElement): JsonElement {
        // equals: [{"kind":"Car","data":{"id":1,"totalWheels":"4"}},{"kind":"Boat","data":{"id":2,"isDocked":true}}]
        val vehicleArray = element.jsonObject["children"]!!.jsonArray

        // equals: [{"type":"Car","id":1,"totalWheels":"4"}, {"type":"Boat","id":2,"isDocked":true}]
        return JsonArray(vehicleArray.map {
            val data = it.jsonObject["data"]!!.jsonObject
            val type = it.jsonObject["kind"]!!
            JsonObject(
                data.toMutableMap().apply { this["type"] = type }
                /*
                //Kotlin 1.4 offers a nicer way to do this:
                buildMap {
                    putAll(data)
                    put("type", type)
                }
                */
            )
        })
    }
}
```

If you declare `Vehicle` class as `sealed` (not just `abstract`), you're already good to go. If you want to keep it `abstract`, then you need to [register all its subclasses](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md#registered-subclasses) in `serializersModule`

```
val module = SerializersModule {
    polymorphic(Vehicle::class) {
        subclass(Car::class)
        subclass(Boat::class)
    }
}
```

and pass it to JSON configuration

```
val kotlinx = Json {
    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
    serializersModule = module
}
```

## UPDATE

**(Alternative approach with combination of `JsonTransformingSerializer` & `JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer`)**

Actually, it's possible to combine these two serializers.
For the sake of justification for this approach, let's imagine that original JSON doesn't have that nice `kind` field, and we have to figure out the actual subtype of `Vehicle` by the shape of JSON. In this case it could be the following heuristic: "if there is a `isDocked` field, then it's a `Boat`, othrewise - a `Car`".

Yes, we may include this logic into `JsonTransformingSerializer` to create class descriminator on the fly:

```kotlin
val type = when {
    "isDocked" in data -> JsonPrimitive("Boat")
    else -> JsonPrimitive("Car")
}
```

But it's more common (and type-safe) to use `JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer` for this. So we may simplify `JsonTransformingSerializer`:

```
object VehicleResponseSerializer : JsonTransformingSerializer<List<Vehicle>>(ListSerializer(Vehicle.serializer())) {
    override fun transformDeserialize(element: JsonElement): JsonElement {
        // equals: [{"kind":"Car","data":{"id":1,"totalWheels":"4"}},{"kind":"Boat","data":{"id":2,"isDocked":true}}]
        val vehicleArray = element.jsonObject["children"]!!.jsonArray

        // equals: [{"id":1,"totalWheels":"4"}, {"id":2,"isDocked":true}] // Note that class discriminator is absent here!
        return JsonArray(vehicleArray.map { it.jsonObject["data"]!! })
    }
}
```

and define `JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer` (for `Vehicle`, not for `VehicleResponse`!) to handle actual serializer selection:

```
object VehiclePolymorphicSerializer : JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer<Vehicle>(Vehicle::class) {
    override fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement): DeserializationStrategy<out Vehicle> = when {
        "isDocked" in element.jsonObject -> Boat.serializer()
        else -> Car.serializer()
    }
}
```

Since `JsonTransformingSerializer` (aka `VehicleResponseSerializer`) is registered for `vehicles` field serialization it's called *before* `JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer` (aka `VehiclePolymorphicSerializer`). Actually, the latter one is not yet called at all. We need to explicitly register it in `serializersModule` and pass it to JSON configuration (regardless of whether `Vehicle` class is declared as `abstract` or `sealed`):

```
val module = SerializersModule {
    polymorphicDefault(Vehicle::class) { VehiclePolymorphicSerializer }
}

val kotlinx = Json {
    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
    serializersModule = module
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much my friend, you're a savior. It seems I completely missed the mark when it came to understanding what tools I actually needed. After this comment, I'm now not sure what is a `JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer` even for.

Comment: Updated my answer with demonstration of `JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer` usage purpose

Comment: Wow! So that's how you use it. Thank you. I have really learned a TON!

In the [documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#content-based-polymorphic-deserialization) they don't even mention you can do it with a configuration. They use it when encoding:

`val string = Json.encodeToString(ListSerializer(ProjectSerializer), data)`

That confused me greatly. It's great to know an alternative! I really wish I could vote you up more than once!

Comment: @МихаилНафталь Could this approach be used to have a polymorphic serializer with a fallback value, e.g. if payload introduce something new not yet handled ? I have implemented a tad ugly by listing all case `when (element.jsonObject["name"]?.jsonPrimitive?.contentOrNull) { /* return serializer for matching type else fallback serializer */}`, but I wonder if there's a better approach